# hard json to pull the values

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

My json has structure:

```
{"0":{"pozycja":0,"znizka":{"0":"0.00"},"autor":{"0":"Cream Software"}},"1":{"pozycja":1,"znizka":{"0":"0.00"},"autor":{"0":"Cream Software"}},"2":{"pozycja":2,"znizka":{"0":"0.00"},"autor":{"0":"Cream Software"}},...}
```

I try tu pull the values like 'znizka' and 'autor', with to loops, no succes. I dont know if it concernes JSON.stringify which I dont have in code(I dont know how to put it in $.getJSON) or it is simply the strange format of json. Thank you for help!

```
$.getJSON("./baza.json", function(data){
console.log(data);
console.log(data.length);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++ ){
       $.each(data[i], function(index, items) {
           var pozycja = items.pozycja;
           var znizka = items.znizka;
           $('.list').append('<li>' + pozycja + '</li>' + '<li>' + znizka + '</li>');
       });
   }

});
```

Comment: By using `getJSON()` you already converted the JSON string into a JavaScript object. This Object is then accessible under `data`. You cannot use a `for` loop to step through the data since you have an object, not an array here. The object does not have a `length` property.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. But how can I combine getJson with JSON.stringify? I searched whole day and no result

Comment: You use `JSON.stringify()` to turn a JavaScript object into a string. But looking at your code I cannot imagine where that might come in useful for you. You should simply access the attributes of your JavaScript object using the approach given by @Farhad below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var json={"0":{"pozycja":0,"znizka":{"0":"0.00"},"autor":{"0":"Cream Software"}},"1":{"pozycja":1,"znizka":{"0":"0.00"},"autor":{"0":"Cream Software"}},"2":{"pozycja":2,"znizka":{"0":"0.00"},"autor":{"0":"Cream Software"}}};
var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(json));
$.each(obj,function(key,value){
   console.log(value.pozycja);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it works, but my json in word has 167pages. I tried to put data into $.parseJSON but no succes.

Comment: It`s quite good start. Thank you, I will try to follow your codding to pull the rest. But if You know, could you tell me how can I set the variable of json from local disc?

Comment: @Joey- Thank you .hope being useful. I'm trying to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: with the info I took I now that if I have to use getJSON which returns object, I need JSON.stringify somewhere in brackets of function getJSON

Comment: If you use getJSON , you do not need JSON.stringify

Comment: I think this link will be for your problem. https://github.com/vigour-io/parse-large-json

Comment: OK. I'm happy to meet you. Tell me if you have any problems. ( bagherlo@live.com )